# AppLinks(verified Deeplinks) in android does not work when app is installed from Google Play

Tags: android, android-deep-link, android-app-links

We have a few `intent-filters` defined in `AndroidManifest` for deeplinks. We also have `assetlinks.json` file placed on our domain at proper location with correct SHA fingerprints. We are facing a weird issue where these App links open our app directly without any chooser in between when app is installed from Android Studio.

Which is also desired behaviour, but, when we upload our app to Google play and download from there these App links open `App chooser` first which is not desired behaviour.

We did some experimentation like creating different intent filters for two different links, removing one link etc but this behaviour remains same. Also double checked SHA fingerprints, they seemed to be fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're saying that you have your `assetlinks.json` file at a proper location, and the JSON itself has correct statements. Then there can be two issues

1. Check whether you've added `autoVerify=true` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the activity in which you've defined the intent filter.
2. Recheck the signed apk's `SHA256` to confirm you're using correct `SHA256` to sign your apk. You can check that using the command

```sh
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile <your_signed.apk>
```

and verify that the same `SHA256`is present in your assetlinks.json file.

- To validate whether your app is actually resolved your app link, use the command

```sh
./adb shell dumpsys package domain-preferred-apps
```

The output would be like:

```
Package: com.test.example
Domains: www.test.com
Status:  always : 200000000

Package: com.test.example
Domains: www.xyz.com
Status:  ask
.
.
.
```

Find your app's package name, then check the `Status` for your package name, if it is `always : <some_number>` then your apk is correctly verified and the app link should work alright, otherwise if value of `Status` is `ask` or `undefined`, then there is some issue which you can refactor following the above-mentioned steps.

Comment: will it differ if I run debug from release?

Answer (score 16):

I know there is an accepted answer, but there's another scenario that someone else may face as I did.

When publishing to `Google Play`, if your app has "**`App Signing by Google Play is enabled for this app.`**", then it doesn't matter what is your `keystore SHA256` when signing your apk on your local machine.

You need to use the `SHA256` from `Google Play Console` -> `Relase management` -> `App signing` -> `App signing certificate`.

**Edit (2021):**
`App signing key certificate` is in a different location now:

1. Select the app from the console.
2. Go to **Release** section.
3. Under **Setup**, select **App Integrity**.

Comment: Yes that solved my problem. My app used App Signing by Google Play. You saved my day thanks.

Comment: Perfect answer, how long did it take for Google to detect the change of the SHA256?